# Put object along the path and then move it (IMG INCLUDED)

Tags: ios, swift, animation, path

I have a problem ( ;) ) and I need your help.

Lets look at the image:

[image: problem visual explanation]

1) I have a path. Lets say it's like this:

```
let bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
bezierPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(10.5, 47.5))
bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(45.5, 23.5), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(10.5, 47.5), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(32.5, 23.5))
bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(84.5, 47.5), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(58.5, 23.5), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(84.5, 47.5))
bezierPath.addLineToPoint(CGPointMake(10.5, 47.5))
bezierPath.closePath()
UIColor.redColor().setStroke()
bezierPath.lineWidth = 1
bezierPath.stroke()
```

2) I have an UIImageView. First question is: How to put it on the top of specified part of the path (A point) ?

3) Second question: How to animate it from point A to B ?

Comment: have you looked into keyframe animations ?

Comment: yes, but this knowledge doesn't helps me solve this problem

Answer (score 3):

By using `CAKeyframeAnimation`, you can create an animation using the path you made

```
let animation = CAKeyframeAnimation()

// Could also be position.x or position.y if you want to animate a separate axis.
animation.keyPath = "position"
animation.repeatCount = 0 // How many times to repeat the animation
animation.duration = 5.0 // Duration of a single repetition

animation.path = bezierPath.CGPath
```

and then attach it to your image's layer

```
imageView.layer.addAnimation(animation, forKey: "move image along bezier path")
```

This other [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31937031/swift-move-uiimage-partly-along-path) helped me form this answer, and if all else fails, you could always refer to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAKeyframeAnimation_class/).

Comment: thank you for answer but it doesn't make animation from point A to B, but through all bezierPath

Comment: Is changing the path itself to start at A and end at B not an option?

Comment: I mean instead of having the above path, change the points defining the path so that the animation would still go through the entire bezierPath, but the path itself would be only from points A to B

Comment: i need to change point B dynamically so it's not a solution for me. and i need the first whole path as well

Comment: @hannad can you tell me how to change UIImageView image based on its bezier path...?

Comment: @hannad i mean image start moving from left_bottom right...? if it reaches Top_Left or Top_Left point can we able to change the image view image . Can you help on this